oracle 19 ADDM addmrpt.sql fails
I am trying to generate a ADDM report from sqlplus with @addmrpt.sql script connected with SYS user and dba privilege.
I am running ORACLE 19.0.0
Unfortunately this doesn't work as the following trace shows.
I am surprised to encounter this error with an account having the sysdba privilege.
Any idea ?
Cheers
cd /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/db_1/rdbms/admin
sqlplus / as sysdba
2024/09/09 15:06:11 SYS AS SYSDBA@oradb> @addmrpt.sql
Instance     DB Name      Snap Id   Snap Started    Snap Level
------------ ------------ ---------- ------------------ ----------

oradb        ORADB         5436  09 Sept. 2024 08:0   1
                   5437  09 Sept. 2024 09:0   1
                   5438  09 Sept. 2024 10:0   1
                   5439  09 Sept. 2024 11:0   1
                   5440  09 Sept. 2024 12:0   1
                   5441  09 Sept. 2024 13:0   1
                   5442  09 Sept. 2024 14:0   1
                   5443  09 Sept. 2024 15:0   1



Specify the Begin and End Snapshot Ids
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Entrez une valeur pour begin_snap : 5436
Begin Snapshot Id specified: 5436

Entrez une valeur pour end_snap : 5443
End   Snapshot Id specified: 5443



Specify the Report Name
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The default report file name is addmrpt_1_5436_5443.txt.  To use this name,
press <return> to continue, otherwise enter an alternative.

Entrez une valeur pour report_name : 

Using the report name addmrpt_1_5436_5443.txt


Running the ADDM analysis on the specified pair of snapshots ...


Generating the ADDM report for this analysis ...


ERROR:
ORA-13605: La tache ou l'objet TACHE_6725 indique n'existe pas pour
l'utilisateur en cours.
ORA-06512: a "SYS.PRVT_ADVISOR", ligne 3991
ORA-06512: a "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", ligne 86
ORA-06512: a "SYS.PRVT_ADVISOR", ligne 7277
ORA-06512: a "SYS.PRVT_ADVISOR", ligne 3923
ORA-06512: a "SYS.DBMS_ADVISOR", ligne 680
ORA-06512: a ligne 1



End of Report
Report written to addmrpt_1_5436_5443.txt
2024/09/09 15:07:24 SYS AS SYSDBA@oradb>


try setting nls_lang in your env to english, not french.

thanks you gsalem, your tips did the trick, addm report has been generated without error.  cheers

as gsalem suggests, setting NLS_LANG to American instead of french did the trick :
2024/09/10 18:21:16 SYS AS SYSDBA@oradb> alter session set NLS_LANGUAGE='American' ;                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Session altered.                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
2024/09/10 18:21:19 SYS AS SYSDBA@oradb> @/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/db_1/rdbms/admin/addmrpt.sql 


=>
...
Using the report name addmrpt_1_5460_5470.txt                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Running the ADDM analysis on the specified pair of snapshots ...                                                                                                                                                   


Generating the ADDM report for this analysis ...


          ADDM Report for Task 'TASK_6761'
          --------------------------------

Analysis Period
---------------
AWR snapshot range from 5460 to 5470.
Time period starts at 10/09/24 08:00:18
Time period ends at 10/09/24 18:00:41

Analysis Target
---------------
Database 'ORADB' with DB ID 2879883713.
Database version 19.0.0.0.0.
ADDM performed an analysis of instance oradb, numbered 1 and hosted at
orasandbox.localdomain.

Activity During the Analysis Period
-----------------------------------
Total database time was 237 seconds.
The average number of active sessions was ,01.


~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

There are no findings to report.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

          Additional Information
          ----------------------

Miscellaneous Information
-------------------------
There was no significant database activity to run the ADDM.


End of Report
Report written to addmrpt_1_5460_5470.txt


Cheers
